# The case for $R[\{x\}] \subseteq A$ $\implies$ $x\in R^{-1}[A]$ holding true.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations

Continuing to work on set theory by myself, starting on relations now, and I've been attempting practice problems. I want to see if what I have of my proof makes sense or I've missed something obvious, and also how to complete the problem. Because the problem isn't too descriptive itself, I've added in some extra context, and it reads as follows:

**Problem.** Suppose $X,Y$ are non-empty, $R$ is a relation, $R\subseteq X \times Y$ and $A\subseteq Y$, then in what case does
$R[\{x\}] \subseteq A$ $\implies$ $x\in R^{-1}[A]$ hold?

Proof:

Since $R[\{x\}] \subseteq A$, and $R[\{x\}] \implies \exists y\in \mathrm{ran}(R) : xRy$, then $R[\{x\}] \subseteq A$ $\implies$ $\exists y\in A : xRy$.

Now going the other way. Since $x\in R^{-1}[A] \implies \exists y \in A: xRy$, then $y \in R^{-1}[A]\implies \exists x \in A : yRx$.

And this is all I really got to, since I'm not sure what it means by 'case', in this context exactly. I'm guessing it's for which choice $A$, but then again I'm not sure. I've also probably made a mistake even in these few steps for a proof. It's hard wrapping my head around relations just starting off. Let me know what mistake I made and how I can correct and complete it.

Answer (score 1):

The premises that $R[\{x\}] \subseteq A$ $\implies$ $x\in R^{-1}[A]$ hold is $R[\{x\}]\neq\varnothing$. To see this you should know the definition of $R[A]$ and $R^{-1}[B]$ clearly.